# Using Objective-C generics for a standalone function?

Tags: objective-c, generics

How to apply Objective-C "lightweight" generics to a standalone function?

I've tried the following syntax but it did not compile with Xcode 8.2.1

```
NSMutableSet<T>* MyFunc<T>(NSSet<T>* input1,NSSet<T>* input2)
{
    // ... function body        
}
```

Google doesn't seem to have an answer for this.

Comment: Objective-C doesn't have generics. It has "lightweight generics" which is not at all the same thing. There is no `MyFunc<T>` syntax. This is Objective-C, not Swift.

Comment: @matt Hence the question.

Answer (score 2):

No. Unfortunately, there are no generic functions in Objective-C lightweight generics. There are only generic classes.